# How to clear action type notification on action click in android Q?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, android-10.0

In android 10, I am using reply type notification. I want to clear that notification on reply action. 
To clear the notification I am using this code:

```
 val notificationManager =
        context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.cancel(notifyId)
```

For variable **notifyId**, I am passing the notification Id.

this code works for all the android versions except android version 10.

This is used to create the reply action:

```
val replyAction = NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
            R.drawable.ic_send,
            btnlable,
            getReplyPendingIntent(
                notificationId,
                title,
                msg,
                senderName,
                action,
                apiName,
                type,
                intentType
            )
        )
            .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
            .setAllowGeneratedReplies(true)
            .build()
```

This is used to create the notification:

```
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, channelID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)   //Set the title of Notification
            .setContentText(msg)    //Set the text for notification
            .addAction(replyAction)
            .setSound(null)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.resources, R.drawable.logo))
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you call .cancel method but I'm doing it on onHandleIntent method of class that inherit from IntentService class and it works:

```
class ApplicationIntentService() : IntentService("AppIntentService") {

    companion object{
        const val BIG_TEXT_STYLE_ACTION1_NAME = "big_text_style.action1"
    }

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        var notificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (intent?.action == BIG_TEXT_STYLE_ACTION1_NAME) {
            notificationManager.cancel(0)
        }
    }
}
```

If you did this too, make sure you register your IntentService implementation in Manifest.xml:

```
    <service
        android:name=".Services.ApplicationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```